# Java White Edge (Buffer) in Mac JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Thanks for the advice. Here is a revised question:

I am creating a program and I had someone make a background for the program. The problem is that I am just placing the image in the frame as a label hoping it would take up the entire space. This would work just fine, but there is a white border edge around the frame making it look less like a background Attached is the image.

[image: Grade Book]

Comment: Got a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or picture??

Comment: Thanks, I added a picture so it's easier to see what I am talking about.

Comment: It looks like you have a border (possibly an empty border) somewhere (I'm not on my Mac at the mo, but I usually have the opposite problem, wanting to add some white space around the window)

Comment: @hovercraft amazing what a little piece of code can do. Think I'll go bang my head against a wall for a while :P